# Is there a feature to maintain the cardinality of the sorted sets in redis a constant?

Tags: redis

Example, I want a key (sorted set) to store only 200 elements. If a new element is added (always with highscore) to the set, an element with lowest score in the set should be deleted automatically, maintaining the cardinality of sorted set a constant.

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no such feature per se, but it's very easy to achieve just that.

First, remember that members are unique so there could be a situation (unless in your use case this isn't so) where adding a new member with a new (high) score will actually update the score of an existing member. So, after each `ZADD` to your key, do [`ZCARD`](http://redis.io/commands/zcard), e.g.:

```
c = redis.zcard('key')
```

If `ZCARD`'s response is > 200, use the difference to trim the sorted set by rank with [`ZREMRANGEBYRANK`](http://redis.io/commands/zremrangebyrank):

```
if c > 200:
   r.zremrangebyrank('key', 0, c - 200 -1)
```

(BTW, if you're only adding one member at a, the above will always remove just one [the lowest ranked] member)

Comment: Thank you for the reply mate. Yeah I could do that, but just queried to know if redis does this automatically.

Comment: No, there isn't. Either do it in the application code or use a Lua script.